# meaning of "shifts of activity" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

I'm currently translating a paper into Spanish for an assignment and I'm having trouble understanding this small paragraph:

> Constraints (C1) and (C2), respectively, constrain shifts of activity
>   on each processing line and on each packaging line in each plant
>   during each period.

My question is, does that "shifts" mean?
a) something changing into another thing or 
b) work shifts (i.e. night shifts)?

Let me know if you need more context to this question and thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose (if it fits with the context) that some productions are transfered from one processing or packaging line to another.

Comment: I read it as meaning "work shifts." The constraints put limits on how you can schedule shifts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the sentence is theoretically ambiguous.  Does *shifts of activities* mean transitions from one activity to another or does it mean time intervals spent on an activity?  If you examine the paper in which the sentence appears *[The Kellogg Company Optimizes Production, Inventory, and Distribution](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA487778)*, you'll find that constraints C(1) and C(2)

> constrain shifts of activity on each processing line and on each
>   packaging line in each plant during each period.

The phrase "each processing line" indicates that the topic is work time spent on a processing line and not a transfer between different lines.  And indeed, it turns out that C(1) is a production constraint, and C(2) is packaging constraint.  Each is defined as a sum over all foods of the product of the number of shifts it takes to process a thousand pounds of that food (shifts/klb) and the target amount of food to be processed (klb).  (Which, of course, must end up less than the capacity of the plant in shifts)

Thus *shifts* here refers to the intervals of time spent on processing lines in Kellogg plants, once again proving that context is everything.

Comment: Thanks for such an accurate answer, I am indeed translating that Kellogg paper and it is reassuring to know that the sentence was ambiguous and that it wasn't just my limited knowledge. 
This is the first time I've ever asked something on StackExchange and I'm pleasantly surprised with how helpful everybody has been. Thanks a lot. :)